# High Memory Usage in my fresh install of Manjaro KDE

Tags: linux, kde, ram, manjaro

I am a normal desktop user. Previously using Linux Lite 2.6. Read about Manjaro and I really like the KDE. So Yesterday I tried to install it and I was struggling with issues. After installation it booted to black screen. Tried nomodeset and radeon.modeset=1, Changed to free driver & non-free driver for graphics, nothing worked. I was frustrated. Today again I tried to search for solution and  found somebody suggesting to delete the virtual box additional plugin files for installing in Virtual Box and direct install (I couldn't understand it properly) also. But I thought there is some issue with Virtualization, SO I went into BIOS and disabled the Virtualization option and did a fresh Install with non-free drivers. WOW it booted successfully. I updated the system and everything seemed fine.

But I see very High Usage of RAM and sometimes high CPU usage even when the system is idle. When I just trying to figure out the drawing application Kritia , my system freezed completely and I was unable to do anything. Same thing happened while watching video on Facebook on Firefox. I had to hard reset my system. Sometime the usb mouse is turned off, I have to unplug and reinsert to make it work again. Then Only I found my system is using High RAM and CPU. **If I just open firefox and chrome the RAM usage increase up to 6 GB.. I have 8 GB** RAM.

**The Temperature is High and my fans are running loud.**

```
prem@prem-pc ~]$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +98.0°C  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +97.5°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +115.0°C, hyst = +115.0°C)
```

Please help me.. I love this Manjaro KDE and want to use it as my main system. [b]I am afraid to change the Graphics driver from non-free to free driver bcoz it might give a black screen while booting.. That is I can't boot my system.[/b]

Here are my system details and screenshots:

```
[prem@prem-pc ~]$ df -BM
Filesystem     1M-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
dev                3728M      0M     3728M   0% /dev
run                3732M      2M     3731M   1% /run
/dev/sda8         24851M   7598M    15968M  33% /
tmpfs              3732M     42M     3691M   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs              3732M      0M     3732M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs              3732M      1M     3732M   1% /tmp
tmpfs               747M      1M      747M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda5         92837M  81686M    11152M  88% /run/media/prem/Prem
/dev/sda2        263924M 162144M   101780M  62% /run/media/prem/24AC7259AC722608
/dev/sda9         63929M     52M    60607M   1% /run/media/prem/a257efe2-e75f-4394-b2a7-8cdd5d0d1bdc

[prem@prem-pc ~]$ free -m
free: Multiple unit options doesn't make sense.

[prem@prem-pc ~]$ sudo swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority                                                                                        
/dev/sda10                              partition       10487804        0       -1                                                                                      
[prem@prem-pc ~]$
```

System Details:

```
[prem@prem-pc ~]$ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: prem-pc Kernel: 4.1.13-1-MANJARO x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.2.0) Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.4.3 (Qt 5.5.1)
           Distro: ManjaroLinux 15.09 Bellatrix
Machine:   System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP Pavilion g6 Notebook PC v: 0692120000204610000610100
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 3567 v: 21.46 Bios: Insyde v: F.6A date: 05/13/2013
CPU:       Quad core AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon HD Graphics (-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4a svm) bmips: 11181
           clock speeds: max: 1400 MHz 1: 800 MHz 2: 900 MHz 3: 900 MHz 4: 1400 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G] bus-ID: 00:01.0
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.17.4 driver: fglrx Resolution: 1366x768@60.03hz
           GLX Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 7400M Series
           GLX Version: 4.5.13399 - CPC 15.201.1151 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:14.2
           Card-2 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series]
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:01.1
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.1.13-1-MANJARO
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 2000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-3: Atheros usb-ID: 006-003
           IF: null-if-id state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (20.8% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST9500325AS size: 500.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 25G used: 7.4G (33%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda8
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 10.74GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda10
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 83.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 193 Uptime: 3:51 Memory: 2739.2/7462.6MB Init: systemd Gcc sys: 5.2.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.421) inxi: 2.2.28
```

Kernel Details:

```
[prem@prem-pc ~]$ mhwd-kernel -li
Currently running: 4.1.13-1-MANJARO (linux41)                                                            
The following kernels are installed in your system:                                                                    
   * linux41
```

Graphics Details:

```
[prem@prem-pc ~]$ mhwd -li                                                                                           
> Installed PCI configs:                                                                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                     
                  NAME               VERSION          FREEDRIVER           TYPE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        video-catalyst            2014.02.04               false            PCI
```

Full Detail:

```
[prem@prem-pc ~]$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Complex
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName: AMD Radeon(TM) HD 6520G
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
        Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
        Memory at f0400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
        Kernel modules: radeon, fglrx

00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series]
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
        Memory at f0444000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
        Memory behind bridge: f0300000-f03fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000efffffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: f0200000-f02fffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f00fffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: f0100000-f01fffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 26
        I/O ports at 4118 [size=8]
        I/O ports at 4124 [size=4]
        I/O ports at 4110 [size=8]
        I/O ports at 4120 [size=4]
        I/O ports at 4100 [size=16]
        Memory at f044e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci

00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18
        Memory at f044d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
        Kernel modules: ohci_pci

00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
        Memory at f044c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
        Kernel modules: ehci_pci

00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18
        Memory at f044b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
        Kernel modules: ohci_pci

00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
        Memory at f044a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
        Kernel modules: ehci_pci

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 13)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel
        Kernel modules: i2c_piix4

00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
        Memory at f0440000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=64

00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18
        Memory at f0449000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
        Kernel modules: ohci_pci

00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
        Memory at f0448000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
        Kernel modules: ehci_pci

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
        Flags: fast devsel

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
        Flags: fast devsel

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
        Flags: fast devsel

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
        Flags: fast devsel
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: k10temp
        Kernel modules: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
        Flags: fast devsel

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
        Flags: fast devsel

00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
        Flags: fast devsel

00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
        Flags: fast devsel

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName: AMD Radeon HD 6470M
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Radeon HD 6470M
        Physical Slot: 2
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f0300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at f0320000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
        Kernel modules: radeon, fglrx

02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
        DeviceName: Atheros 802.11b/g/n WiFi/BT Combo
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1785
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at f0200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
        Expansion ROM at f0280000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
        Kernel modules: ath9k

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
        DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
        I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
        Memory at f0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169

04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3567
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
        Memory at f0100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Expansion ROM at f0110000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
        Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

Screenshots below

**Please help me out.**

[image: High RAM Usage]
[image: top]

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue. Try using free drivers; for most people it reduces RAM usage.